# Html radio button labels don't select the proper radio button (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

(Ruby on Rails application)

I'm having a problem with selecting radio buttons by clicking their designated labels (I have multiple forms on the same page).

In my application, I have a *Conversations* resource, where in its show page *Users* can send *Messages* into the conversation. In 'conversations/show' users can *React* to each others' messages. I use a *ReactionExample* model to create a few reaction_examples at a time, which users can select and create their own new instance of Reaction from.

**here is the show action in conversations controller**

```
def show
   @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:id])
   @messages = @conversation.messages.all
   @reaction_examples = ReactionExample.all #These are "like", "hate", etc...
end
```

**here is my 'conversations/show' view**

```
<% @messages.each do |message| %>
   <p><%= message.user.first_name %> says <%= message.content %></p>
   <%= form_for message.replies.build, url: reaction_conversation_path(@conversation) do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :message_id, value: message.id %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
      <% @reaction_examples.each do |example| %>
         <%= f.radio_button :reaction_example_id, example.id %>
         <%= f.label :reaction_example_id, example.phrase, value: example.id %>
      <% end %>
      <%= f.submit "Send reaction" %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Here is my problem:** in this view ('conversations/show') there will be multiple forms to send a reaction. Each of these forms will have more than one radio button and label with the same value, just a different :message_id on each form. I would like to be able to select a reaction radio button by clicking its label, but there are multiple forms on this page with radio buttons WHICH HAVE THE SAME LABEL VALUE. So when I click a radio button label on the *third* *or* *fourth* message down on the page, it selects the radio button on the *first* message up on the page. It's because they technically have the same value since the same ReactionExample id's are being used in each radio button in the forms.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should make the value/ id unique which will help you to check the selected radio button.

Comment: @SnehaT any advice on how to do that while still keeping the id of the ReactionExample which it is based on?

Comment: Why dont you use messageid to make your reaction unique for particular form someway like this: id: "reaction_for_#{message.id}"  assign this id to your reaction_example radio button....